Configuring database connection for design time vs run time
I am currently reading a book and I have this part that is a little bit hard to understand for me. For context, I should note that, the reason of this concept being hard to grasp is because I have not used it in my n-layered ASP.NET Core MVC projects and they worked just fine.
The book says that the code below is for configuring SQL connection at runtime.
public static void ConfigureSqlContext(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration) =>
    services.AddDbContext<RepositoryContext>(opts =>
        opts.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("sqlConnection")));

Now if you are asking what the problem is, let me tell you. In my other projects when I configured this code in my program.cs, I could still work with migrations without needing to run my project. So, I quite don't understand why it was working fine then while I didn't add the code that I mentioned below. (I consider run time CTRL+F5 or F5, if I am wrong, please kindly correct me).
In the earlier chapter, the book mentions about migrations on design time and shows the code below:
public class RepositoryContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<RepositoryContext>
{
    public RepositoryContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();

        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<RepositoryContext>()
            .UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("sqlConnection"),
                b => b.MigrationsAssembly("CompanyEmployees"));

        return new RepositoryContext(builder.Options);
    }
}

So I searched a bit about design time, but as you can guess, I didn't understand the use of the code because of me using AddDbContext for both scenarios (I didn't know the concept of design time tbh).
Summary of my questions:

Why do we need design time database configuration and what happens if I don't use it as I clearly didn't use it in my other projects?
Can I not configure runtime configuration if I configure the design one? If so, why?


I could still work with migrations without needing to run my project - it doesn't mean that the EF tools didn't use the context from your project, wrapped up in a bit of code so they could create and use it as-represented, to perform design time migrations, when you instructed them to do so. You may have noticed that your project needs to be buildable in order to have EF tools perform e.g. a migration.

@flackoverstow So, EF Core did the work for me in the background without me knowing? Why use design time configuration then?

In case you still want to use the tools, but you want some different thing about your project that will trip the tools up e.g. you're taking away something the tools expect to be there for their baked-in behavior - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli lists some examples at the end


Why do we need design time database configuration and what happens if I don't use it as I clearly didn't use it in my other projects?

Firstly, the design time database configuration is not needed for your application. This is used for design time testing, like you need this database contain some test data or need testing some specific function or else and don't want this also inside database become production database(runtime).
From doc:
A design-time factory can be especially useful if you need to configure the DbContext differently for design time than at run time, if the DbContext constructor takes additional parameters are not registered in DI, if you are not using DI at all, or if for some reason you prefer not to have a CreateHostBuilder method in your ASP.NET Core application's Main class.

Can I not configure runtime configuration if I configure the design one? If so, why?

I suggest you should configure runtime configuration firstly, then create the design one based on your requirement, since the design one is just used for design time testing.
Actually, you could configure the design time database and runtime dbcontext at same time, if a class implementing this interface is found in either the same project as the derived DbContext or in the application's startup project, the tools bypass the other ways of creating the DbContext and use the design-time factory instead.

You should perhaps quote and cite the paragraph beginning "A design-time factory can be especially.." and also "if a class implementing this interface" because they are not your words, but verbatim from MSDN
